# Extract certain columns from 2-d array and form a new one

Tags: python, arrays

This is what I currently have:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

This is what my expected outcome looks like:

```
[[1,3],[5,7],[9,11],[13,15]]
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `numpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
x = []

for v in t:
    x.append([v[0], v[2]])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking:

```
s = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
new_data = [[a, b] for a, _, b, c in s]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [5, 7], [9, 11], [13, 15]]
```